# Двоичное представление числа

Tags: php, python, ruby

сколько бит в двоичном представлении числа n^n?

Answer (score 5):

Очевидно,

```
1 + [log_2(n^n)] = 1 + [n log_2 n].
```

То есть, вы *можете* поместить число `n^n` в переменную, содержащую не менее `1 + [n log_2 n]` бит.

(`[х]` — целая часть числа `x`.)

Если у вас под `^` подразумевается возведение в степень, конечно.